# Using parse.com as my backend how do i store and access pictures, videos and other static data that won't be in relational database?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, api, parse-platform

I am using parse data core for my iOS swift project. Parse states in their free tier they offer 20GB for file storage and 20GB for database storgae. I have been using their iOS SDK with swift, however I am struggling to understand how i can add photos and videos to the static file sever (20gb limit) I am working stricly with xcode and swift for mobile app, i don't have a backend or rest API for my app.

Comment: Use a PFFile - https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html

Comment: Let me clarify and expand on my question:  For example lets say the iOS app offers cars for sale. It would allow users to search nearby cars (using their locations) With parse I wouuld run a query using geolocation and display cars in a tableview with high res photos. parse does not offer dashboard GUI to add photos and link that url to a particular object . IS there a easy way to upload lets say pictures of 100 cars and link them to car objects which has a particular geo location

Comment: Yes, PFFile.  You will need to write some code (either javascript if you want a web site or in your app) that creates PFFile objects and you can then store the reference to the PFFile in a Parse database column.  The PFFile is effectively a URL that you can fetch using any HTTP framework or using the Parse framework

Answer (score 0):

As another user said, one option is to use a PFFile object in a normal data table. You would query it by table name and some other identification key, same as any other Parse object.

Since you specifically asked for static file servers, it might be possible to host in your cloud code directory, and then create a cloud code JS hook to access it via API.

Comment: A PFFile isn't an object in a data table - it is a separate file.  You can store PFFile references in a Parse table, but all it is really storing is a URL